# With the Python, what is the decimal precision required for volume and price on Kraken's REST API?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, precision, kraken.com

I want to use Python to interact with the Kraken REST API (https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025180232-REST-API-command-line-client-Python-#python).  I'm US-based.  I was trying to figure out what kind of decimal precision I would need for a "ETHUSD" pair,

```
$ ./krakenapi AddOrder pair=ETHUSD type=sell ordertype=limit price=1.00 volume=50 oflags=post
```

however, when I query

```
https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs
```

I do not see this pair listed.  What kind of precision (decimal places) would be required or is it not possible to trade ETHUSD within Kraken's REST API?

Answer (score 0):

`ETHUSD` is listed as an `altname` in the [`AssetPairs`](https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs) query you mentioned, under the id/key of `XETHZUSD`, with a price decimal precision of 2 as shown in the `pair_decimals` key:

`"XETHZUSD":{"altname":"ETHUSD","wsname":"ETH/USD","aclass_base":"currency","base":"XETH","aclass_quote":"currency","quote":"ZUSD","lot":"unit","cost_decimals":5,"pair_decimals":2,...`

This means you can place an order of 1600.01 USD but not 1600.001 USD for the `ETHUSD` pair.

For more information, please read the Kraken's documentation on [Price decimal precision](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/4521313131540-Price-decimal-precision).

Comment: Thanks, is the "cost_decimals" the precision for the amount/volume of currency wanted?  For example, I could not order less than "0.00001" of XETHZUSD?

Comment: Decimal precision and minimum volume required for an order are two different things. The latter is given under the key `ordermin`, which for the `ETHUSD` pair is `0.01`, meaning that you cannot place an order of less than `0.01` unit of `ETH`. There's also the key `costmin` with a value of `0.5` for `ETHUSD`, which means that an order must be of at least `0.5` USD in cost. Decimal precision refers strictly to the number of digits after the decimal point allowed in an order.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification.  I would like to stick to decimal precision then -- how do I figure that out?  Presumably I can buy ".5" ETH (since the minimum is .01, but can I buy ".512" ETH or ".5123412431234123421432" ETH?